# Java: How to loop through dropdown and click all values using selenium/cucumber

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm new to JAVA and working on a dropdown which have 2 values on expand. I have written piece of code to expand and click on one value at a time. Below code clicks on 1st option in dropdown but failing to click the 2nd option. Please let me know where am failing

```
List<WebElement> services = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role="tree"]"));
for (int i=0; i<=services.size();i++) 
{
    services.get(i).click();                
}
```

As shown below, I have this as dropdown which have two values and I have to loop through it and click one option and the fields displayed when one option is selected varies. i.e. , when I select family visa option, I will see 2 fields and when I select labor visa, I see 4 fields. Please let  me know how I can handle this?

```html
<ul class="select2-results__options ps-container ps-theme-default" role="tree" id="select2-j_idt2033-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" data-ps-id="7c9094ae-c960-f1d8-d348-1e3a1cf822f1"><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2033-result-llff-038" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Family Visa</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2033-result-l4bk-039" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">Labor Visa</li><div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px;"><div class="ps-scrollbar-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div></div><div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; right: 3px;"><div class="ps-scrollbar-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div></div></ul>​
```

Comment: Is your code compiling fine? `By.xpath("//*[@role="tree"]")` doesnt look like it will. I might be wrong. I'd try `By.xpath("//*[@role='tree']")`..

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML too.

Comment: When you click an element in the dropdown does it remain expanded or does it collapse?

Comment: @Reezo, the dropdown collapse when I click element

Comment: @haC  - I have added snippet from the HTML on which I need to work. kindly suggest.

Comment: Can somebody suggest how I can handle above problem. Thanks!